# CSS phone ringng animation

Tags: html, css

I want to have my font awesome icon "ring" each 1 seconds, by ring I mean having a css animation which makes the phone look like if it where ringing (maybe a brief rotation with transform origin center?), I'm a noob with css animations:

```
<div style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius:50%; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; background-color:white;"><i class="LAYOUTnav7_links_button_icon fa fa-phone fs_bigger main"></i></div>
```

Any help?

Comment: That's a ridiculously complex and detailed animation that you're asking for, and also rather ambiguous. Do you want it to go side to side? Rotate at all? An example would help. And we're also not a free code-writing service; have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Comment: have you tried to google this before posting? There's plenty of examples like this one https://codepen.io/callmenick/pen/XdwmeV

Answer (score 3):

You can use animation and keyframes to do this, here is an example:

```css
.phone {
  display:block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin:50px auto 0;
  color: #9e9e9e;
  animation: ring 4s .7s ease-in-out infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 4px;
}

@keyframes ring {
  0% { transform: rotate(0); }
  5% { transform: rotate(30deg); }
  10% { transform: rotate(-28deg); }
  15% { transform: rotate(34deg); }
  20% { transform: rotate(-32deg); }
  25% { transform: rotate(30deg); }
  30% { transform: rotate(-28deg); }
  35% { transform: rotate(26deg); }
  40% { transform: rotate(-24deg); }
  45% { transform: rotate(22deg); }
  50% { transform: rotate(-20deg); }
  55% { transform: rotate(18deg); }
  60% { transform: rotate(-16deg); }
  65% { transform: rotate(14deg); }
  70% { transform: rotate(-12deg); }
  75% { transform: rotate(10deg); }
  80% { transform: rotate(-8deg); }
  85% { transform: rotate(6deg); }
  90% { transform: rotate(-4deg); }
  95% { transform: rotate(2deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-1deg); }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <span class="phone fa fa-phone"></span>
</div>
```